# Why .attr() is working fine and setting a .src is not

Tags: javascript

I have two versions od code,
This one is not working:

```
 $('#customMenu > li > a').click(function()
            {
                if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active')
                {
                    $('#customMenu li img').each(function() {

                         $(this).src='/_layouts/GAzotyBranding/Images/menuUnselected.png';
                    });
                    var image = this.previousSibling;
                    image.attr('src','/_layouts/GAzotyBranding/Images/menuSelected.png');

                    $('#customMenu li ul').slideUp();
                    $(this).next().slideToggle();
                    $('#customMenu li a').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                }
           });
```

and this one is working fine:

```
$('#customMenu > li > a').click(function()
            {
                if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active')
                {
                    $('#customMenu li img').each(function() {
                        $(this).attr('src','/_layouts/GAzotyBranding/Images/menuUnselected.png');

                    });
                    var image = this.previousSibling;
                    image.src='/_layouts/GAzotyBranding/Images/menuSelected.png';
                    $('#customMenu li ul').slideUp();
                    $(this).next().slideToggle();
                    $('#customMenu li a').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                }
           });
```

the only difference is in

```
$('#customMenu li img').each(function() {
                        $(this).attr('src','/_layouts/GAzotyBranding/Images/menuUnselected.png');
```

My Question is simple, why first one is not working?

Comment: jQuery objects don't have an `src` property.

Comment: @PeeHaa — What would the console say? You can set arbitrary properties on an object without an error being thrown.

Comment: Ah sorry you are correct obviously. tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in both cases you're wrapping the raw DOM node with the jQuery wrapper, so you're just setting some property on a non-DOM object.

To make the first work, you'd need to have `this.src = '...';`, since `this` will point to the raw DOM element.

Comment: replace  $(this).src= with this.src = '...'?

Answer (score 0):

Because setting a `src` property on a jQuery object simply doesn't do anything. There's no defined behaviour for it and nothing pays attention to it. jQuery objects are not DOM objects.

Using `this.src` instead of `$(this).src` would work.